# how to create a button that renames selected nodes in treeview.

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button called btnNew that creates a parent node in the treeview called whatever the input is in the inputbox.

```
    private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fName;
        fName = Interaction.InputBox("Enter folder name:");
        if (fName == "")
        {
            TreeNode treeNode = null;
        }
        else
        {
            TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(fName);
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
        }
```

What i need next is a button called btnRename that will use a InputBox to rename the selected node. I'm aware I should be using forms for these pops ups not input boxes. Any advise or code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tv.SelectedNode != null)
        tv.SelectedNode.Text = Interaction.InputBox("Rename the node name from " + tv.SelectedNode.Text);
}
```

Comment: Add check `if (tv.SelectedNode == null) return;`